# How to change the SimpleDateFormat to jodatime?

Tags: java, datetime, jodatime

I need to change the `SimpleDateFormat` to some other format which is equivalent in jodatime. 
Here's the code which needs to be changed.

```
public static String dateFormat(Date date, String format)
{
    SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat(format);
    return sdf.format(date);
}
```

I have tried to use DateTimeFormatter.

```
public static String dateFormat(DateTime date, String format)
{
    DateTimeFormatter dtf = DateTimeFormat.forPattern(format);
    DateTime tempDateTime =  dtf.parseDateTime(date.toString());
    return tempDateTime.toString();
}
```

But I am getting Error.

Comment: Well, what have you tried so far? In particular, have you read http://www.joda.org/joda-time/key_format.html ?

Comment: AFAIK, for common use cases the format JodaTime uses is much the same as SimpleDateFormat.  You just need to use the classes from JodaTime.

Comment: Uh oh. You awoke the Skeet.

Comment: By the way, an alternative to hard-coding and passing format strings is to use [Locale](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Locale.html)-sensitive formats. See [style](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/apidocs/org/joda/time/format/DateTimeFormat.html#forStyle(java.lang.String)). You specify a character of 'S' for short, 'M' for medium, 'L' for long, & 'F' for full formats. Pass one such letter for date and another for time, or pass '-' to omit either portion. The language, style, and ordering of the words & numbers is adapted to country/culture and language of your Locale object.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Well, I look for you in the documentation of Joda Time and `SimpleDateFormat`. As you can see there, the pattern definitions are unfortunately not the same. If you translate from `SimpleDateFormat` to Joda-[DateTimeFormat](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/apidocs/org/joda/time/format/DateTimeFormat.html), then you have to note following items:

Change Y to x (so called week-year).

Change y to Y (year-of-era) and maybe changing the chronology, too (from ISO to Gregorian/Julian)

W is not supported in Joda Time (week of month), hence no replacement!

F is not supported in Joda Time (day of week in month), hence no replacement!

Change u to e (day number of week - ISO order, not localized), available since Java 7.

The symbol S is handled differently (I suppose in Joda Time better because of correct zero padding).

The zone symbol z is in Joda Time not allowed for parsing (maybe this is the current cause of your problems - **you have not shown your pattern format or your exception yet**).

The zone/offset symbol Z is handled better in Joda Time, for example allows colons in offset etc. If you need latter you can use X in SimpleDateFormat which has the replacement Z in Joda Time.

**Some tests added:**

Following sample code demonstrates the different handling of format symbol S.

```
String s = "2014-01-15T14:23:50.026";
DateTimeFormatter dtf = DateTimeFormat.forPattern("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSS");

DateTime instant = dtf.parseDateTime(s);
System.out.println(dtf.print(instant)); // 2014-01-15T14:23:50.0260

SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSS");
Date date = sdf.parse(s);
System.out.println(sdf.format(date)); // 2014-01-15T14:23:50.0026 (bad!)
```

Another test for format symbol z (is that your problem???):

```
String s = "2014-01-15T14:23:50.026PST";
DateTimeFormatter dtf = DateTimeFormat.forPattern("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSz");

DateTime instant = dtf.parseDateTime(s);
System.out.println(dtf.print(instant)); // abort

Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Invalid format: "2014-01-15T14:23:50.026PST" is malformed at "PST"
    at org.joda.time.format.DateTimeFormatter.parseDateTime(DateTimeFormatter.java:866)
    at time.JodaTest8.main(JodaTest8.java:83)
```

SimpleDateFormat can do this zone name parsing (although at least dangerous sometimes):

```
String s = "2014-01-15T14:23:50.026PST";

SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSz");
Date date = sdf.parse(s);
System.out.println(sdf.format(date)); // 2014-01-15T14:23:50.026PST
```

Comment: Why this ("Change y to Y (year-of-era)") translation?   Lowercase 'y' seems to be an identical symbol (year) between both pattern definitions?

Comment: @cellepo In Joda-Time, the symbol "Y" represents a year-of-era (minimum value is 1 in standard ISO-chronology) while the symbol "y" (lower-case) represents the so-called proleptic year which counts down to zero and even negative values for the far past. And only that is the main difference between both year definitions - in the far past.